# Confusing apache configuration with passenger and mod_proxy

Tags: apache, passenger

I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure apache for the following:

www.server.com/mstar should go through passenger

but anything else, such as:
www.server.com/
www.server.com/index.hmtl
etc
should go through mod proxy.

So, I would need something to check if it has /mstar as the first component of the path and if so, have it served through passenger. But anything else should go through mod_proxy.

something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName beta.server.com

    DocumentRoot /home/ruby/webapps/m-star/current/public

    <Location /mstar>
        PassengerEnabled on
        RailsBaseURI /mstar
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://beta.server.com:8890
    ProxyPassReverse / http://beta.server.com:8890
    <Location />
        PassengerEnabled off
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, this of course is not working.

Can you give me some pointers on what to look at in the apache configurations and passenger configuration to accomplish this?

I got the following to work:

I got the following to work as I described:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName beta.server.com

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

PassengerEnabled off

ProxyPassMatch ^/(?!mstar)(.*) http://beta.server.com:8890/$1
ProxyPassReverse / http://beta.server.com:8890

DocumentRoot /home/ruby/webapps/m-star/current/public
<Directory "/home/ruby/webapps/m-star/current/public">
    PassengerEnabled on
    RailsBaseURI /mstar
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```